# Refactor dotted namesapces in VS2010 Pro?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How do I refactor the namespace of components that use dotted notation in my `Visual Studio 2010 Pro` solutions (`C#`)?

I have tried selecting `Refactor->Rename` or pressing F2 with the cursor at the head of the namespace string, but this only works for the first part of a dotted namespace string (e.g. "a.b.c.d" selects "a").

I've also tried highlighting the entire namespace and selecting `Refactor->Rename` but I'm presented with a dialog message that says: `"Please select a symbol to be renamed.`"

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

VS doesn't have anything built into it for this (yet).

ReSharper can do it for you:

[image]

For this i removed the `.Entities` from the namespace (sorry, i had to disguise some namespaces there, but you get the idea).

If you don't want to download a trial version of ReSharper and do it (hey, you may end up liking it!), then your best option is to ensure you have all your projects loaded, change the namespace at the top of the relevant class files, then attempt a recompile. All the faulty declarations or namespce useage will now show up in the *Error List* window - except for some XAML ones. (Some XAML useages will show up straight away, others will only show up at run time. You should be able to do a global search + replace on .xaml files only, this is reasonably safe, but make sure you have your files either backed up or managed in a source control repository).

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I was hoping it would be part of the IDE and easier than that! VS isn't cheap and tools like Eclipse seem to do it out of the box, and for free, so I don't think it's unreasonable to expect to do this without commercial plugins like ReSharper. Oh well, I guess I'm just spoilt. Thanks again.

Comment: @Matt, that is a fair enough observation, but the reality is you will only need to do this very infrequently. Also if the IDE did everything then it would kill most of the extensions market for it and get MS accused of anti-competitive behaviour :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't find/replace do this for you? Search for `namespace a.b.c.d`, replace with `namespace d.e.f`; find `using a.b.c.d`, replace with `using d.e.f`.

Comment: Yes, it does, but just not as convenient. Again, I think I'm just spoilt by other IDE tools.